# Php mysql из базы брать сообщения только для определенной комнаты

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы chats (с полями id,message) и room(id_room,name_room)
Как брать сообщения только для определенной комнаты. то есть перешел в первую комнату там определенные сообщения, перешел в другую комнату, там уже другие сообщения

Comment: Что-то у вас в вопросе связующего поля между таблицами не видно.

Comment: Свзяь между таблицами по id сделал в phpmyadmin, как теперь всё это правильно вывести?

Comment: Тот же вопрос.. где связь между таблицами? Какие поля вы связали? Можете уточнить? Просто обычно в таблице чатс, было 3е поле id_room к примеру..

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить в `chats, id_room` чтобы связать таблицы и после вот такой закров по названию комнаты:

`SELECT chats.message 
 FROM chats 
  LEFT JOIN room ON room.id_room = chats.id_room 
 WHERE room.name = 'название комнаты'`

или ее идентификатору:

`SELECT chats.message 
 FROM chats 
  LEFT JOIN room ON room.id_room = chats.id_room 
 WHERE room.id_room = 'id'`